# Internet Recovery. Unlike Monterey, Sierra OS X Utilities starts with wi-fi connected, even after a nvram reset and a disk erase. How?

Tags: wifi, recovery, disk-format, utilities, nvram

On boot, when I press **Shift+Option+Command+r**, a globe appears with a dropdown box to choose my ssid and password. After some time the **Sierra** Utilities starts and my wi-fi connection is enabled.

This is not happening when I press **Option+Command+r** on Boot to get to the **Monterey** utilities. I get the same Globe with the dropdown box, but after the Utilities screen starts, my wi-fi is not connected, so it doesn't seems to be saved.

I never inserted my wi-fi credentials on a final installation, only on the globe screen and on the Monterey utilities when I attempted an Online Recovery that I canceled. After that, I made a nvram/smc reset and formatted the disk again (disk utility > show all devices > choose the ssd disk > erase).

How is this happening? Is it possible that Sierra, unlike Monterey, can get the wi-fi information from the globe part?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add screen shots to help explain things a little better?

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately I can't. Can you give me some tips to clarify my question? Thanks.

Comment: Screenshots always go a long way to showing what you are talking about. 